# Own Events in Java not able to modify Classobjects?

Tags: java, android, events, interface

this is My Situation:

I want to make two classes communicate with each other. So MainActivity is
making a new Object of SomeOtherstrangeClass.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements myEventListener {

    private TextView txtHelloSet;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtHelloSet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHello);

        SomeOtherStrangeClass someOtherStrangeClass = new SomeOtherStrangeClass();
    }


    @Override
    public void someEvent(int e) {
        Log.v("[Listener]", "SomeEvent triggered. Number: " + e);
        txtHelloSet.setText("Event came in!");
    }
}
```

#

```
public class SomeOtherStrangeClass {

    public  SomeOtherStrangeClass(){

        EventThrower eventThrower = new EventThrower();
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();


        eventThrower.addListener(mainActivity);
        Log.v("[Listener]", "Throwing event");


        eventThrower.someEvent(13);

    }
}



interface myEventListener extends java.util.EventListener {
    void someEvent(int e);
}

public class EventThrower {

    private List<myEventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<myEventListener>();


    public void addListener(myEventListener toAdd){
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }
    public void removeListener(myEventListener toRemove){
        listeners.remove(toRemove);
    }


    public void someEvent(int e){
        for(myEventListener el : listeners)
            el.someEvent(e);
    }

}
```

So this is how I'am doing it. But the Problem is, that when an event is thrown its like I'am still calling the Methode someEvent which is in MainActivity in SomeOtherStrangeClass. So I'am not able to modify any Objects in MainActivity. It's like they are not existing. I'am getting a NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Why this is so? 
Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the instance of `MainActivity` that is currently in foreground in order to recognize any callbacks in it.

Try changing the constructor for `SomeOtherStrangeClass` like this:

```
public  SomeOtherStrangeClass(myEventListener listener) {
        EventThrower eventThrower = new EventThrower();
        eventThrower.addListener(listener);
        Log.v("[Listener]", "Throwing event");
        eventThrower.someEvent(13);
    }
```

Then, in onCreate() of your activity,

```
SomeOtherStrangeClass someOtherStrangeClass = new SomeOtherStrangeClass(this);
```

Comment: unfortunately addlistener cannot be applied to android.app.Activity. Did you mean:  SomeOtherStrangeClass(MainActivity listenerActivity)?

Comment: No, I've edited the mistake. Use a `myEventListener` as an argument for SomeOtherStrangeClass' constructor. Since your `MainActivity` implements `myEventListener`, it can be used with `addListener`.

Answer (score 1):

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

You are doing something wrong here. It is not supposed to create Activity objects like this. You should rethink about your application logic.

Comment: i found this code example @stackoverflow... i just want to throw an own event in SomeOtherStrangeClass and be recognized by MainActivity...